# SQL Server : listing table names and its ids

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005

I want to list all the specified tables with its ids contained in SQL Server.

For example:

**Client** table

```
| id | foo  |
|:---|:----:|
|  1 | This | 
|  2 | Col  |
```

**User** table

```
| id | bar  |
|:---|:----:|
| 1  | That | 
| 2  | Col  |
| 3  | Col  |
| 4  | Col  |
```

And I want to generate a result like this:

```
| TableName |  ID  |
|:---------:|:----:|
|  Client   |   1  | 
|  Client   |   2  |
|  User     |   1  |
|  User     |   2  |
|  User     |   3  |
|  User     |   4  |
```

What I have done is to list all the desired table name, but I don't know how to list its ids

```
SELECT t.name AS TableName
FROM sys.tables as t
WHERE t.name = 'Client'
   OR t.name = 'User'
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
| - | TableName |
|---| --------- |
| 1 |  Client   |
| 2 |   User    |
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Just those two tables, or many more as well?

Comment: @APH 6 more as well, but Yogesh's answer should be sufficient?

Comment: Yeah, for 8 tables I'd use that solution.  For many tables, you might need a dynamic sql solution instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need `UNION ALL` :

```
SELECT 'Client' AS TableName, ID   
FROM Client 
UNION ALL
SELECT 'User', ID
FROM User;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need `UNION`

```
SELECT T.Name,
       C.ID
FROM Sys.Tables T CROSS APPLY
     Clients C
WHERE T.Name = 'Clients'
UNION
SELECT T.Name,
       U.ID
FROM Sys.Tables T CROSS APPLY
     Users U
WHERE T.Name = 'Users'
```